# How to make - Hybrid cornerRadius - Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uiview, rounded-corners

I hope all are doing well.

Here's the following, I need to make the cornerRadius like the one in the example, but in the icon, he doesn't change at all and in a Carousel, he only makes the bottom corners, not the top ones.

What can I do accomplish this? My corners don't have the same radius on all sides.

[Icon Corners Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3LZe.png)

I have a function for the cornerRadius:

```
func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
  let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                          byRoundingCorners: corners,
                          cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
  let mask = CAShapeLayer()
  mask.path = path.cgPath
  self.layer.mask = mask
}
```

In my icon I make the call this way:

```
    bigIconContentView.roundCorners([.topRight, .bottomLeft], radius: 30)
    bigIconContentView.roundCorners([.topLeft], radius: 10)
```

And in my Carousel I'm calling this way:

```
    bStoreImage.roundCorners([.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 20)
    beaconsContentView.roundCorners([.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 20)
    beaconsContentView.roundCorners([.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 7)
```

What I'm doing wrong? What can I do to make them work and make these sides with different Radius?

I can make two roundCorners call to the same element but with different attributes? Like I did in my examples?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are calling twice `roundConer(_, radius:)`, you are overriding each time `self.layer.mask`, so you should get the last one only applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's focus on `roundCorners(_ corners: radius:)`

```
func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
    let someNewMask = somethingNew(corners, radius: radius)
    self.layer.mask = someNewMask
}
```

You are doing:

```
bigIconContentView.roundCorners([.topRight, .bottomLeft], radius: 30)
bigIconContentView.roundCorners([.topLeft], radius: 10)
```

Which in the ends, is doing this:

```
let someNewMask1 = somethingNew([.topRight, .bottomLeft], radius: 30)
bigIconContentView.mask = someNewMask1
let someNewMask2 = somethingNew([. topLeft], radius: 10)
bigIconContentView.mask = someNewMask2
```

So you are doing:

```
bigIconContentView.mask = someNewMask1
bigIconContentView.mask = someNewMask2
```

You see the issue? You are overriding `bigIconContentView` `mask` with a new one each time (the last one called).

You have to apply the different corners all together (there is nothing complicated in corner radius)

```
extension UIView {
    func roundCornersRadii(topLeft: CGFloat = 0, topRight: CGFloat = 0, bottomLeft: CGFloat = 0, bottomRight: CGFloat = 0) {
        let path = UIBezierPath()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: topLeft, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width - topRight, y: 0))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: bounds.width - topRight, y: topRight),
                    radius: topRight,
                    startAngle: -CGFloat.pi/2.0,
                    endAngle: 0,
                    clockwise: true)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: bounds.width - bottomRight))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: bounds.width - bottomRight, y: bounds.height - bottomRight),
                    radius: bottomRight,
                    startAngle: 0,
                    endAngle: CGFloat.pi/2.0,
                    clockwise: true)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bottomRight, y: bounds.height))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: bottomLeft, y: bounds.height - bottomLeft),
                    radius: bottomLeft,
                    startAngle: CGFloat.pi/2.0,
                    endAngle: CGFloat.pi,
                    clockwise: true)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: topLeft))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: topLeft, y: topLeft),
                    radius: topLeft,
                    startAngle: CGFloat.pi,
                    endAngle: CGFloat.pi/2.0,
                    clockwise: true)
        path.close()

        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

Adding sample test:

```
let superView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))
let subview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200))
superView.backgroundColor = .red
subview.backgroundColor = .blue
subview.roundCornersRadii(topLeft: 20, topRight: 30, bottomLeft: 40, bottomRight: 50)
superView.addSubview(subview)
```

[image]
or in your case:

```
let superView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))
let subview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200))
superView.backgroundColor = .red
subview.backgroundColor = .blue
subview.roundCornersRadii(topLeft: 20, topRight: 30, bottomLeft: 40, bottomRight: 50)
subview.roundCornersRadii(topLeft: 10, topRight: 30, bottomLeft: 30)
superView.addSubview(subview)
```

[image]

Comment: That's it! Worked it flawlessly for me. I appreciate your help.